# The size of the test-vector for Falcon pqc are wrong?

Tags: testing, nonce, falcon, post-quantum-cryptography

"In the Falcon documentation, there is code provided by the authors, and within it, there is an implementation under the 'c' folder where they perform testing on their algorithms. They include a test with vectors; however, it does not match the size that, according to their specifications, it should have. For example, one vector is as follows:

```
static const char *const KAT_SIG_512[] = {
    "cd3f225a65b2c6e155c2af799308af940212633fa519a4b4ddd22048ff8a7d06",
    "sample 0",
    "0900070058......."};
```

Where the first element is the nonce, the second is the message, and the third is the signature. In this test vector, the nonce has a length of 32 bytes. However, in the documentation, they state the following: '**nonce string r (40 bytes)**.' I hope someone can clarify this doubt for me."

Did not find in the documentation the reason why this nonce size can be used.